# Nancyfx routing return all params

Tags: routes, nancy

I want that nancy return me all routing data.

Example I pass `xxx.com/somebody123`. I want that nancy return me `somebody123`

```
Get["([^>])"] = parameters =>
    {
        return parameters.; // how make it?
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an entire section in the Nancy Wiki about routing.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#pattern

You could do:

```
Get["{name}"] = parameters =>
{
     return parameters.name;
};
```